# Error: The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file when trying to perform a rollback

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I am trying to perform a rollback but I am getting the following error

```
The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file.´
```

I do have the database URL in my pom file as you can see below ,so I don't think that's the problem

### pom File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.petapilot</groupId>
    <artifactId>migrations</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Migrations</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <liquibase.mysql.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306</liquibase.mysql.url>
        <liquibase.mysql.username>root</liquibase.mysql.username>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The database has a password . Do I have to write it too?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the way of configuring Liquibase through pom.xml file. I think you could try this way:

- instead of providing all database properties inside  tag of pom.xml, create "liquibase.properties" and populate various properties relevant to liquibase(DB) in this file.
  For help with creating "liquibase.properties" file, visit [this link](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html)
- Try using configuration similar to below in your existing pom.xml file:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.my-group.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>Liqui<SampleDb>-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.9.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                          <dependency>
                              <groupId><db_type></groupId>
                              <artifactId><db_type></artifactId>
                          </dependency>
                      </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
```

- You could also try the following way by correcting your existing pom file. [This link](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/maven-pom-file.html) says to include liquibase attributes inside `<configuration>` section. May be try surrounding the liquibase attributes in your POM file in `<configuration>` section as below:

```
<configuration>
    <changeLogFile>changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
    <url>MyJDBCConnection</url>
    <username>dbuser</username>
    <password>dbpassword</password>
</configuration>
```

*Yes, DB password is required for configuration*

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used the liquibase.properties approach

Comment: great! properties file is the neat and recommended way anyways. Good to know it helped!

Comment: Using a `<configuration>` section was helpful in my situation.